# Get question mark in beginning of request with mod_rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

### Scenario:

When the user enters `myhomepage.com/username` he/she should be redirected to `myhomepage.com/?username`.

Respectively: `myhomepage.com/index.html?username`

if the user enters the url with the question mark : `myhomepage.com/?username`, `mod_rewrite` should be ignored.

**EDIT:**

This is what i tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html?$1
```

Comment: What do you currently have in your .htaccess?

Comment: RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html?$1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for an empty querystring in a `RewriteCond`

```
RewriteEngine On
# Rule only applies when we have an empty querystring
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_QUERYSTRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html?$1
```

Comment: i added the empty query string condition but it still doesn't seem to work . is there a way i can debug my problem ?  i wrote random text in .htaccess and got an error that i know the file is at least read by the system . i use alert(window.location.search); in the webpage to check the received username . thanks for your help !

Comment: Do you have other rules following this in your .htaccess? If so, add `[L]` to the rule to prevent further processing

Comment: i added [L] but still don't receive the url with the question mark character when i check in index.html with alert(window.location);

Comment: does mod_rewrite actually change the url for the target website ? or is it another command i have to use ?

Comment: @user1020751 It changes the URL if you use `[R]`. Without the R flag, it routes the URL internally, invisibly to the user.  To make it actually redirect the user's browser, use `[R]`